# Get all children elements by an element attribute in an XML file using Dart / Flutter xml package

Tags: xml, flutter, dart

This is an XML example of what i'm trying to achieve:

```
<bookshelf>
  <book id="1">
    <title lang="en">Growing a Language</title>
    <chapter number="1">What's a Language?</chapter>
    <chapter number="2">Basics</chapter>
    <chapter number="3">Examples</chapter>
    <chapter number="4">Exam</chapter>
  </book>
  <book id="2">
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <chapter number="1">What's XML?</chapter>
    <chapter number="2">Theory</chapter>
  </book>
  <book id="3">
    <title lang="en">Personal Computer</title>
    <chapter number="1">What's a PC?</chapter>
    <chapter number="2">Hardware</chapter>
    <chapter number="3">Operating system</chapter>
  </book>
</bookshelf>
```

Is there a way to get all the  elements values given the book id number? something like:

```
document.getElement("bookshelf")?.getElement("book id=\"2\"")?.findAllElements("chapter").map((node) => node.firstChild).forEach(print);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `xml` package, and parse the input to an `XmlDocument`. Then navigate through it using `findElements` to find the right child elements.

These return iterators, so you can use standard methods like `first` and `where`.

So, for example:

```
  final doc = XmlDocument.parse(input);
  doc
      .findElements('bookshelf')
      .first
      .findElements('book')
      .where((e) => e.getAttribute('id') == '2')
      .forEach(print);
```

Depending on the structure of your XML, you may be able to skip finding the bookshelf and `first` by using `findAllElements('book')`

Comment: Thanks Richard. Where method was the key!

Answer (score -2):

you can use xml2json package for converting json.
[enter link description here](https://github.com/VeyselSahn/stflow_answers/blob/main/xml_elements/xml_elements/bin/xml_elements.dart)

In this link, i made an example.